Coding a performant flexible scientific code with Python
I aim to code a PDE flexible fast PDE solver. I read and noticed multiple approaches:

Python + Numba
Python + Cython
Python + some compiled language (c++/fortran)

The equations to be solved are Navier-Stokes equations. I am thinking of using an input file (containing the mesh, the computational domain, boundary conditions) that the program would parse. I will look into other options to have a better idea of how I would code it.
It is for learning purposes.
Questions:

How are each approach comparable?
Is parallelization easy to add (MPI/OMP)?
GPU portability?
Maintainability?


Are you doing this as a learning exercise, or are you trying to build a tool that others will use?  Is this a solver for a particular PDE boundary value problem, or are you trying to build a more general tool that can solve a variety of PDEs?  Why not use an existing framework like FEniCS?

I think any informative answer to this question will require you to supply more details regarding the type of PDE and the spatial domain. You can do simple problems any way you want, but complexity and scale require more specific tools.
